# Неверное контрольное слово для логина Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть небольшой сайт, на котором есть форум. При регистрации пользователю приходит письмо с логином и паролем, а так же ссылка для изменения пароля. При переходе по этой ссылке пользователь вводит свои данные для изменения пароля, но при этом появляется ошибка Неверное контрольное слово для логина (Хотя пользователь с таким логином существует). В чем может быть ошибка и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что Вы переделывали шаблон компонента смены пароля и забыли скрытое поле